What is the scope of Quant SE?
We should consider what will appear in our FAQ as well as the guiding tone of questions to open the site.

I agree with chrisaycock, though I think a more broad subject list would be appropriate.
Have a look at the subjects covered by "Quantitative Finance" journal. I think it's a nice guideline. Sometimes it's hard to say what is "quant" and what is general finance, but subjectively I would rather err on covering more ground than eliminating interesting topics just because they are not "quant" enough (of course I mean graduate/academic level finance).
The journal covers:


Agent-based modelling
Anomalies in prices
Asset-liability modelling
List item
Behavioural finance
Bounded rationality
Corporate finance
Corporate valuation
Derivatives pricing and hedging
Evolutionary game theory
Experimental finance
Extreme risks and insurance
Financial econometrics
Financial engineering
Learning adaptation
Liquidity modelling
Market dynamics and prediction
Market microstructure
Operational risk modelling
Portfolio management
Price formation
Risk management
Trading systems
Web-based financial services



This is a good list too.

My own view is that this should cover graduate-level material for professionals and MFEs. This can include:

derivatives pricing
risk assessment
portfolio construction
statistical arbitrage
high-frequency trading


As for what should appear on the FAQ, perhaps include a few links to the broad-topic (ie, beginner) items that we want to keep off the main site.
http://www.quantnet.com/master-reading-list-for-quants/

I agree with the premise of this answer (namely, the site should focus on experts), but your list might be a little too specific?

@Shane Could you add an answer on other topic areas? I want to actively avoid stuff like investing advice or discretionary trading.

This "master reading list" has been making the rounds because of the nice CSS on the site, but what really makes it authoritative?

I don't know, but this is definitely the right question to be asking. Right now the questions are either super noobish or about some very specific model that's not clarified.
For example the questions about "local stochastic volatility model" and "real options valuation model" ... obviously there is not just one such thing. It seems like the askers have a page of a book open and are seeing some terms they want to explore more.
Maybe we can prompt question-askers to tell us what book they're getting the question from, when appropriate.

Absolutely; asking for clarification and training question askers is part of our role here.
